# What is the currently accepted strategy for ado.net and SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database

I know that EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling (TFH) has been deprecated.  I've found a couple of different articles that discuss building your own retry policies by checking error numbers when a fault occurs but I'm wondering if there is some other package that handles this?  Also, in the old TFH code, there was a connection retry and also a command retry.  With the documentation I can find, there is no discussion on retrying a command at all.  Are transient faults now handled exclusively through the connection?

Answer (score 2):

Polly is a great library for dealing with transient fault handling: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.

Here's their tagline: *"Polly is a .NET 3.5 / 4.0 / 4.5 / PCL (Profile 259) library that allows developers to express transient exception handling policies such as Retry, Retry Forever, Wait and Retry or Circuit Breaker in a fluent manner."*

You're not using Entity Framework, right? Because EF supports using a differrent 'execution strategy', and they provide the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` which handles transient faults to the database.

Comment: No, not using EF.  It's legacy code that was written in ado.net and the effort to move it over to EF would be significant.

Comment: OK - too bad. Because - as said - it has this stuff baked in. Then you could go with wrapping your calls in Polly.